Upgrade Laravel 8 to Laravel 11
Upgrading Laravel 8 to 11: Dependency Issues
I'm upgrading a Laravel project from version 8 to 11. Here are my old and new dependencies:
Old Dependencies:
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^6.10",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.16",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.4",
    "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.21",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.11"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
},

New Dependencies:

"require": {
    "php": "^8.2",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^6.10",
    "google/apiclient": "^2.16",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^11.0",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^4.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
    "laravel/ui": "^4.5",
    "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^2.0",
    "spatie/laravel-html": "^3.11",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.11"
},
"require-dev": {
    // Currently empty
},

Issue: I removed some dependencies that caused errors during the upgrade and reinstalled them afterward. However, I’m now facing issues with the following:
illuminate/support
facade/ignition

I’ve tried running the following commands:
composer update --with-all-dependencies
composer require facade/ignition:*

This is my first time upgrading Laravel. Do you have any tips or know what problems I might face during this upgrade?
Thanks in advance!

Laravel should be upgraded one version at a time.
facade/ignition was replaced by spatie/laravel-ignition in Laravel 9. Even spatie/laravel-ignition is no longer necessary in Laravel 11.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade
If you have the knowledge to upgrade all versions, you can skip intermediate versions, but if not, you should proceed in order.

Second this, you will want to upgrade incrementally, and change things that are applicable to your project. Otherwise, you may want to consider starting from a fresh laravel 11 package, as a lot and I mean a lot has changed.
